# iOS, How can prevent CloudKit deleting the last record in a concurrent situation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

My app need at least one student record.

However all other student records can be deleted, I don't need a specific record, just any one record.

I've setup cloudkit subscriptions.

I could end up with two users on the same icloud account deleting different student records. When notifications are recived on each devices this would result in no student records.

For example
User A is using an iPad and deletes student record 1, this is sent via iCloud to User B.
User B is offline on an iPhone and deletes record 2, he then regains connectivity and notifications are sent.
Both users loose both records.

I thought I'd arrived at a solution, where I do a check and add a new student record if none were found.

However I could (and did in testing) end up with two students added concurrently via this method.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I've been reading... confliction resolution, denying / accepting notified transactions in app. This doesn't have to occur on notifications, but in your fetch too. I've decided I don't need notifications, after all I'd have to cater for changes while my app was running, all the time.